# Is there a way to translate/ animate divs/images along a curve path in javascript and css?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have a list of images , which need to scrolled on left or right arrow key press. But the scrolling needs to along a curve like a parabolic path . Is there a way to do this in javascript and css? If not not what should i use for this?

Comment: Hello Sachin and welcome to Stack Overflow.
it is more likely to get a response if you show what you have tries

Comment: The answer is yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

for your next question, please provide examples of what you have tried, what has failed, what you have researched or found out, etc. In general, please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Nonetheless, I wanted to see what I can code in a few minutes before leaving work so here is a little something that might send you along the right way:

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');

const path = function(x) {
  return 0.1 * (x * x); // or any other functon
}

let x = 0;

const updateCircle = function() {
  const y = path(x); // get y from x
  const speed = 5;
  const translateX = speed * x + 'px';
  const translatey = speed * y + 'px';
  const transform = `transform: translate(${translateX}, -${translatey})`;
  circle.setAttribute('style', transform);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  let move = false; // set move to true if left or right arrow pressed

  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft": // moving left means decreasing x values
      x--;
      move = true;
      break;
    case "ArrowRight": // moving right means increasing x values
      x++;
      move = true;
      break;
  }

  if (move) { // let or right arrow pressed
    window.requestAnimationFrame(updateCircle);
  }
}, true);
```

```css
.circle {
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  transition: transform 170ms linear;
}

body::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: block;
  content: 'click here to focus the snippet';
  color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```